# Android Tesseract Data Path in init

Tags: android, android-studio, ocr, tesseract

I am making an Android OCR app using the tesseract tools. I have tried some of the links found online. However, for all them, my app crashes after
baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang)

I have tried all sorts of values for Data_Path found online. I have my eng.traineddata in assets/tessdata.

```
//DATA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/MyOCRApp/tessdata";


AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        String[] files = new String[0];
        try {
            files = assetManager.list("");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (String currPath:files){
            if (currPath.equals("tessdata")){
                DATA_PATH = "///android_asset/"+ currPath;
            }
        }
```

These are a couple of the examples I have tried using. Also, I don't think my app is installing in the SD card, it is installing in the internal memory. I hope that is not the issue.

Comment: The problem already solved by this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38347384/directory-assets-tessdata)

Answer (score 0):

The language data has to be on the device's storage, not inside the app assets.

So if you put it on the SD card in `/MyOCRApp/tessdata` you'd use:

```
final String datapath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyOCRApp";
final boolean initialised = api.init(datapath, "eng"));
// ...
```

Comment: But i dont want to individually put it on sd card. I want it to work from the app itself.

Comment: It must be on the device's storage. I'd try copying it from the assets folder to the SD card on app start up.