# Directory: assets/tessdata

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I've downloaded an OCR text recognizer from github.

My problem is: I want to launch my app without being online, but everytime I install the apk on my phone, it starts downloading the english language and the tesseract OCR engine.
I've found an online guide which says I have to create a folder in the assets folder called "tessdata" and put the eng.traineddata and the osd.traineddata in this folder.

I've tried but the download process still starts when I install the app for the first time. 
What can I do to make this app completely offline?

Answer (score 5):

First, in your project directory in computer (`YourProjectDirectory\app\src\main`) create `assets` folder, int this folder create another `tessdata` folder. In tessdata folder put your .traineddata files, these will be transferred in your phone when your project starts running. You can download .traineddata files for your language [HERE](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata).

For transferring .traineddata files into phone I use this code:

```
public class TessOCR {
public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.example.dainius.ocr";
public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment
        .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/AndroidOCR/";
public static final String lang = "eng";

private static final String TAG = "TESSERACT";
private AssetManager assetManager;

private TessBaseAPI mTess;

public TessOCR(AssetManager assetManager) {

    Log.i(TAG, DATA_PATH);

    this.assetManager = assetManager;

    String[] paths = new String[] { DATA_PATH, DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" };

    for (String path : paths) {
        File dir = new File(path);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.v(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " on sdcard failed");
                return;
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "Created directory " + path + " on sdcard");
            }
        }
    }

    if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata")).exists()) {
        try {
            InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata");
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/", lang + ".traineddata"));

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();

            Log.v(TAG, "Copied " + lang + " traineddata");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy " + lang + " traineddata " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    mTess = new TessBaseAPI();
    mTess.setDebug(true);
    mTess.init(DATA_PATH, lang);

}


public String getResults(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    mTess.setImage(bitmap);
    String result = mTess.getUTF8Text();
    return result;
}

public void onDestroy() {
    if (mTess != null)
        mTess.end();
}
}
```

This code checks whether in your phone exists file with directory `/AndroidOCR/tessdata/eng.traineddata` and if not, creates one and puts .traineddata file here.
For this to occur, in your OnCreate you will have to create `AssetManager`, which will let you to access that .traineddata file you placed in your computer in your project.

So in your OnCreate in MainActivity:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
TessOCR tess = new TessOCR(assetManager);
```

Also, to allow your Android project write data into your phone in `AndroidManifest.xml` file you need to add permision line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is the method I use personally and it works without any errors. If you have any, search in google for answers and if you still can't find an answer, post in comments.

Comment: It's the same for osd.traineddata (text recognition engine)?

Comment: It should be, I think. Just try `public static final String lang = "eng";` variable change with "osd", then it should put it into the same directory. I actually never needed osd and tesseract have not tried to download it for me, so I can't be 100% sure. If you need to check and upload both of these files in phone, just repeat that TessOCR constructor function two times with different .traineddata names (lang variables).

Comment: I've used your code, and it works... more or less: It creates the folder in the phone storage, but it keeps asking me to download these file, and if I cancel the code lines where the download is asked, it shows a message dialog which says that the engine is being initialized... and if I remove this part too I have only black screen.